# Как создать обработчик формы wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вопрос для гуру Wordprees.
Допустим у меня есть форма авторизации на сайте. В параметре action задан путь обработки "/controller".

Как и где можно написать обработчик данной формы, то есть по сути обработчик для http://site.com/controller ? 
Можно ли реализовать данное непосредственно в файле functions.php шаблона Wordpress ?

Comment: У вас, как минимум, три пути: либо реализовать свой url через `WP_Rewrite`, либо сослаться на физический файл плагина, которому придется подклюбчать ядро вордпресса самому, либо воспользоваться [префикс-экшеном](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)), который позволит ловить запросы через admin.php. Если потребуются дополнительные пояснения, позже смогу написать полный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Иду читать, если будет время напишите ответ. 
Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, можно воспользоваться готовым решением

```
<?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
```

тут все уже реализовано. Этот код выведет стандартную готовую логин форму.